# AWS Apigateway portal Cognito redirect problem with Custom domain and DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront

I have AWS API gateway portal with Cloudfront distribution. Also I have registered custom domain and DNS to point to that portals distibution. However portals Sign in button gives an error when trying to use that portal providing custom domain Url.
Cognito Sign in gives a message "An error was encountered with the requested page.".
Also on address bar there is error message in url (error=redirect_mismatch)
"https://myapp-foobar-cogn.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=changed2smthng1elses100va5ljjd1lq"

So something brokes in authentication when trying to authenticate with Cognito when site is opened from custom domain and redirected to Cloudfront url.
What I am missing here? When I use cloudfront original distribution url this same sing in button works and athentication success.

In Cloudfront
I have setted this custom domain to Cloudfront settings as
"Alternate domain name (CNAME)" Also optional "Custom SSL certificate" has been given.

Answer (score 0):

Just after asking I found that I have to setup "Allowed callback URLs" and also "Allowed sign-out URLs"  to Cognito Hosted UI.
That led to another problem. Authentication works, but portal application data is empty. I guess it can't retrieve information from S3 buckets or something like that.
So now I can log in to portal with Cloudfront url -> Data exists
Log in with custom domain url -> No data at all and some functions (invite new user) gives an error.